# Using enums from a class (C++)

Tags: c++, enums

I'm using a library that has classes with a number of enums. Here's an example

```
class TGNumberFormat
{
  public:
  // ...
  enum EAttribute {   kNEAAnyNumber
    kNEANonNegative
    kNEAPositive
  };
  enum ELimit {   kNELNoLimits
    kNELLimitMin
    kNELLimitMax
    kNELLimitMinMax
  };
  enum EStepSize {   kNSSSmall
    kNSSMedium
    kNSSLarge
    kNSSHuge
  };
  // etc...
};
```

In the code I have to refer to these as `TGNumberFormat::kNEAAnyNumber` for example. I'm writing a GUI that uses these values very often and the code is getting ugly. Is there some way I can import these enums and just type `kNEAAnyNumber`? I don't really expect any of these names to overlap. I've tried various ways of using the `using` keyword and none will compile.

Comment: I would use a typedef local to the function (e.g. `typedef TGNumberFormat NF;`, allowing, e.g., `NF::kNELLimitMin`).  Though, I'd argue that it's better to type out the names.

Comment: `struct X : TGNumberFormat {};`. Then you can use them as `X::kNEAAnyNumber`. I don't recommend you do this, as `TGNumberFormat` (ostensibly) holds more meaning than whatever shorter name you come up with for `X`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using these constants all over in your code, it might be beneficial to create your own header that redefines the values in a namespace.  You can then `using` that namespace.  You don't need to redefine all of the values, just the names of the enumerators.  For example,

```
namespace TGEnumerators
{
    static EAttribute const kNEAAnyNumber(TGNumberFormat::kNEAAnyNumber);
    // etc.
}
```

Alternatively, you can typedef `TGNumberFormat` to a shorter name in the functions or source files where you use it frequently.  For example,

```
typedef TGNumberFormat NF;
NF::EAttribute attribute = NF::kNEAAnyNumber;
```

I'd argue that the latter approach is superior, and if used judiciously at block scope, is a fine practice.  However, for use across a file, I think it'd be preferable to use the full names of the enumerators, for clarity.

Comment: +1 I can't count how many times I've seen a bare enumerator and wondered where on Earth it came from because it was hidden by a sneaky `typedef` or `using`.

Comment: Just a small remark: for value redifinition (your first method), I think it is better to use `static const EAttribute` instead of plain `EAttribute`.

Comment: @Mark To make clear that the linkage is internal. It's not necessary for the code to work, but it more self-describing I think.

Answer (score 0):

If your using c++11 you can use the keyword auto to deduce the type:

```
//the compiler will see auto and know to use: TGNumberFormat::EAttribute
auto attribute = TGNumberFormat::kNEAAnyNumber;
```

> compiled with: g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp

If you're not using c++11, consider using typedefs as mentioned by @James McNellis
using macros are not recommended because they won't obey the rules of scope-- typedefs will.

Answer (score 0):

One other way that's possible but involves a bit more work up front is to define a batch of consts that you then use instead:

e.g.

```
const TGNumberFormat::EAttribute AnyNumber = TGNumberFormat::kNEAAnyNumber;
const TGNumberFormat::EAttribute NonNegative = TGNumberFormat::kNEANonNegative;
...

attribute = AnyNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Live with it.
2. `#define AnyNumber TGNumberFormat::kNEAAnyNumber`

*Runs for cover...*